# Lock and unlock cells in Excel based on color in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a vba macro to unlock all yellow cells (colour index 36) and lock all non-yellow cells. The below code works; however, I am struggling to get this in a For loop to have it run through each sheet in my workbook (and not just run on 'Sheet1').

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In Sheet1.UsedRange
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36 Then
            cell.Locked = False
        End If
    Next

    ws.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really do want this to run on ***every*** worksheet in your workbook, the following should work:

```
Sub test()
    'declarations
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'loop through each worksheet (ws) in active workbook
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'remove protection
        ws.Unprotect
        'lock all cells
        ws.UsedRange.Cells.Locked = True
        'loop through used range
        For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
            'unlock cells based on color index
            If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36 Then cell.MergeArea.Locked = False
        Next
        'reprotect sheet
        ws.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a "Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class" error when I run this. I have double checked that all sheets are in fact unprotected, but can't figure out what is causing it.

Comment: When it errors, you can use the immediate window in VBE to find out *where* the issue is. Enter `?ws.name` to find out what sheet the issue is on, and then `?cell.address` to find the cell in question.. Maybe a merged cell?

Comment: I've altered my answer, to deal with merged cells - which I suspect was causing the error.